# automate and change row and column using php for loop

Tags: php, html, forms, for-loop, css-tables

I am having trouble trying to output the following 3 tr rows in a php block using for loop.

Currently I have:

```html
<tr>

   <td>R1/C1 </td>

   <td>R1/C2 </td>

 </tr>

  <tr>

   <td>R2/C1 </td>

   <td>R2/C2 </td>

 </tr>

  <tr>

   <td>R3/C1 </td>

   <td>R3/C2 </td>

 </tr>
```

How do I make a FOR Loop to automatically increment for the rows and columns?

Would it be something like:

```
for($i=0 ; $i<3; $i++){

echo <tr>

   <td>R1/C1 </td>

   <td>R (i dont know)/C(i dont know) </td>

 </tr>
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other than all the missing quotations... sure.

Comment: You need a nested for-loop

Comment: @DanielGale well, no, you don't need nested `for` loops to display numbers from `1` to `3`..

Comment: No you don't, but if you want to count C1-C3 while also counting R1-R3 for each column counted you will need a nested for loop

Comment: @DanielGale i see your point, but it looks like a beginner question, no need to complexify too much with nested concept. i prefer to assume the simpler rather than the complex. from the example he provided, C1 and C2 are always the same, if nothing from the OP suggests it's coming from dynamic value, it could be 2 or more static rows in each loop cycle, like in his example (or else, i'd rather write a detailled answer than a comment)

Comment: @Kaddath I agree that it shouldn't be more complex than needed. I was leaning on the point that the OP wanted a "for loop" and showed that the R1 value will be the same per row but the column level data appears to change. I would consider a nested for loop at this level beginner as well. If the columns were in an array then a simpler example with a foreach would be all that's needed.

Comment: Yes, I was leaning towards a nested for loop as well just dont know how I would go about or code it. It is leaned more towards a beginners level but the loop must be a for loop. There are only 2 columns and 3 rows. I do not want to keep making more rows after C2/R3. Would the C and the R be in different loops... hints the nested?